# Separate GWT CodeServer from Jetty

Tags: java, spring, gwt, intellij-idea

I'm working with a GWT-Spring project, normally I use the default configuration to run the project with SuperDevMode (I use IntelliJ).

I'd like to run SuperDevMode without the embedded Jetty and I know to achieve that I just need to use: -noserver

I tried to use that option and at the same time run a Tomcat server using the same artifact I have with GWT to run the backend, but it's not working.

My question is, how can I run different servers, one for the GWT compiler and other for the backend code?

I just want to avoid to recompile the GWT application each time I have to restart the backend.

Let me know if there's a way to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the best practice, but it works.

1. compile your GWT project
2. create a dynamic web project
3. copy the host page, images, css, etc from the web content folder of the GWT project (including the compiled GWT code) to the WebContent folder of the newly created web project.
4. make sure that the newly created web project does not have GWT Facet in the project properties (otherwise everytime you start the Tomcat server, GWT will compile your source)
5. add the new project to your Tomcat server Run Configuration and start it
6. create a GWT Run Configuration (SDM), that looks like that:
   [image]
   and start with Debug

Hope that helps.

Comment: The -war arg may need to be used to point to the war output directory.

Comment: There is one other way to do it, and that is use a Java Launcher and start the CodeServer entrypoint with -launcherDir /pathTo/Output/war and module for arguments.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do it, this gave me some clues.